# Plot output using knitr is missing panel

Tags: html, r, plot, markdown, knitr

I've a data frame with 3 columns. The column Days is a factor vector with 2 factors "weekdays" and "weekend"

Using this code, I create a plot of the 2 factors having 2 panels on top of each other:

```
xyplot(Avg_Steps ~ Interval | Days, groups = Days, data = agg_subdata_avg, type = "l", layout = (c(1,2)))
```

However, when using this same code in a R markdown file and use knitr to create a HTML output, the top panel does not show. What is causing this discrepancy?

```
{r, echo = TRUE, fig.width=6, fig.height = 6}
library(lattice)
xyplot(Avg_Steps ~ Interval | Days, groups = Days, data = agg_subdata_avg, type = "l", layout =      (c(1,2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to replicate the behavior you describe using the code you've provided is to first filter out all rows in "agg_subdata_avg" which contain "weekend" in the "Days" column and then proceed with plotting.

Just to double-check that both levels are represented, you might try plugging this line into your **Rmd** file next to the `xyplot` function and then re-knit:

```
print(unique(agg_subdata_avg$Days))
```

As far as why the code would work perfectly in the **R** console but fail when creating the HTML file, *it's most likely that* [1] the two data frames are not actually equivalent (Is it possible that you made changes to one and not the other?).

If none of this helps, then your best bet is probably to give more info re: version of **R**, **knitr**, etc. and perhaps add a reproducible example.

[For what it's worth, I tried knitting a file that included your code and everything worked as expected.]

[1] Or, more accurately: "whenever this kind of thing happens to me it's because"...

Answer (score 0):

I make now the same assignment from "Reproducible research" course. 
And I got the same result: only one of the two panels shows in the html file.

As it turned out, in process creating R markdown file I used option `cache = TRUE` and while I did not remove it I got incorrect old plot created at the first time.

Answer (score 0):

Previous hint is quite useful : "print(unique(agg_subdata_avg$Days))".

I got the same problem and found the root cause is because the locale setting.
The course assignment require to populate a new column with factor values ("Weekday","Weekend"). You have to check how you populate the data when you compare the date value.